# TCL regsub plus sign error

Tags: regex, tcl

What is wrong with this? I can't seem to figure it out

```
regsub {+} $input { }
```

I get this error: `couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid`

Answer (score 4):

The `+` character is regular-expression metasyntax: it means match the preceding sub-RE one or more times. (For example, `a+` matches one or more `a` characters.) Because of this, if you want to use a raw `+` you have to either escape it with a backslash (`\+`) or in a character set (`[+]`), or put the RE engine into one of its restricted modes; starting the RE with `***=` makes the rest of the RE be a literal to match. Specializing to your case, `***=+` matches a plain `+`, and `***=++` matches two plusses in a row, etc.

Comment: If you're using `[+]` or `\+`, be aware that `[` and backslash are both _Tcl_ metasyntax characters…

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `+` char:

```
regsub {\+} $input { }
```